# If $(u,v,w)$ is linearly independent, is $(Au,Av,Aw)$ also linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

**If $\{u,v,w\}$ is a linearly independent set,**

$(1)$ Is $\{u-v-w,-u+v-w,-u-v+w\}$ linearly independent?

$ \quad \quad a(u-v-w) + b(-u+v-w) + c(-u+v+w) = 0 $ $\iff$ $ (a-b-c)u + (-a+b-c)v + (-a-b+c)w = 0$

$\quad \quad $ **Since $u, v, w$ are linearly independent**, $\begin{cases}
a-b-c=0 \\ 
-a+b-c = 0 \\ 
-a-b+c = 0
\end{cases}.$

$\quad \quad$ **This system only has the trivial solution** $a = 0 , b = 0, c =0.$

---

$(2)$ If $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $\text{span}\{u, v,x\}\ne\text{span}\{u, v,w\},$ then is $\{u, v,w,x\}$ linearly independent?

**$ \quad \quad $ No, let $x=v,$ is a redundant vector in $\{u,v,w,z\}.$ So, $\{u,v,w,z\}$ is linearly independent.**

---

$(3)$ Let $B =\{u,v,w\}$ be the $n\times3$ matrix where $u,v,w$ are the $3$ columns. Does any $\text{REF}$ of $B$ have a non-pivot column?

**$ \quad $ No, the $3$ vectors $u,v,w$ are linearly independent, $\text{REF}$ of $B$ is an identity matrix, so it has exactly $3$ non-pivot columns.**

---

$(4)$ Suppose $\{Au,Av,Aw\}$ is linearly independent, must $A$ (a $n\times n$ matrix) be invertible?

$ \quad \quad $ No, it does not.
$ \quad \quad $ Let $\{Au,Av,Aw\}=\{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\}$ **which is linearly independent.**

$ \quad \quad $ A = $ \left(\begin{array}\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \end{array}\right) $ and $ \{u,v,w\} = \{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0) , (0,0,1,0)\} $

$ \quad \quad $ **but, A is not invertible, since** $ det(A) = 0 $

I am not sure if the matrix I have chosen for A in part (4) is appropriate? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: I am voting to close this post because it features **four separate** questions at once. A question on this site is meant to be just that: *a question*, singular. You are more than welcome to post them separately though.

Answer (score 1):

If $aAu+bAv+cAw=A(au+bv+cw)=0$, then $au+bv+cw=0$ (whence $a=b=c=0$) or $au+bv+cw$ is an eigenvalue-$0$ eigenvector of $A$. While invertible $A$ lacks such eigenvectors, completing the proof that $Au,\,Av,\,Aw$ are linearly independent, if $A$ is singular it does have such an eigenvector. That leaves undetermined, however, whether such an eigenvector is expressible in the form $au+bv+cw$; if it's not, the linear independence of $Au,\,Av,\,Aw$ still follows. So if you want an example where such linear dependence fails, try e.g. $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,\,1,\,0),\,u=i,\,v=j,\,w=k$.